# On a Google maps overlay, how do I create lines between svg elements in D3

Tags: html, google-maps, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I want to call my function drawlink to draw lines between some of my elements. I tried adding an each call to my link variable to call it, i.e.:

```
  var link = layer.selectAll(".link")
      .data(data.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .each(drawlink);
```

but that did not work. Before I add that line I have got the stage where the Google Map has drawn and my 4 svg elements have been drawn.

How should I be doing this ? Other code improvement comments very welcome too.

stations.json

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"A","long":0.0000,"lat":51.4800},
    {"name":"B","long":-0.1684,"lat":51.4875},
    {"name":"C","long":-0.2043,"lat":51.5096},
    {"name":"D","long":-0.1269,"lat":51.5295}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":0,"target":1},
    {"source":0,"target":2},
    {"source":0,"target":3},
    {"source":2,"target":3} 
  ]
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<style>
html, body, #map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.link {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.stations, .stations svg {
  position: absolute;
}

.stations svg {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.stations circle {
  fill: brown;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 1200px; height: 600px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Create the Google Map…
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
  zoom: 12,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5195, -0.1269),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});

d3.json("stations.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

  overlay.onAdd = function() {
    var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
        .attr("class", "stations");

    overlay.draw = function() {
      var projection = this.getProjection(),
          padding = 10;

      var node = layer.selectAll(".stations")
          .data(data.nodes)
          .each(transform)
        .enter().append("svg")
          .each(transform)
          .attr("class", "node");

      var link = layer.selectAll(".link")
          .data(data.links)
        .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link");

      node.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 4.5)
          .attr("cx", padding)
          .attr("cy", padding);

      node.append("text")
          .attr("x", padding + 7)
          .attr("y", padding)
          .attr("dy", ".31em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

      function transform(d) {
        d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.lat, d.long);
        d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
        return d3.select(this)
            .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
            .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
      }

      function drawlink(d) {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
        }     
    };
  };

  overlay.setMap(map);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried, rather than passing the source and target positions to the .each() on the link, just doing it inline, so instead of .each(), just do .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; }).attr('y2' .... and so on ? If you could put together a fiddle that would be great :)

Comment: d3s node, link magic happens when you build a force layout diagram and specifically when you call `d3.layout.force()`.  I don't see you doing that in your code...  Why not just loop your links, loop up the lat/long from your nodes and draw a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a slight deviation in your approach.  Instead of appending an `svg` per station, I'd append a single `svg` (if you need to draw lines from station to station you'll have to do this) and then append a `g` per station.  The lines then are an easy loop over your links, calculate position and add the lines:

Here's the 3 main positioning functions then:

```
  function latLongToPos(d){
    var p = new google.maps.LatLng(d.lat, d.long);
    p = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(p);
    p.x = p.x - padding;
    p.y = p.y - padding;
    return p;
  }

  function transform(d) {
    var p = latLongToPos(d);
    return d3.select(this)
      .attr("transform","translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")");
  }

  function drawlink(d) {
    var p1 = latLongToPos(data.nodes[d.source]),
        p2 = latLongToPos(data.nodes[d.target]);
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('x1', p1.x)
      .attr('y1', p1.y)
      .attr('x2', p2.x)
      .attr('y2', p2.y)
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
```

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .link {
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    
    .stations,
    .stations svg {
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .stations svg {
      width: 1200px;
      height: 600px;
      padding-right: 100px;
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .stations circle {
      fill: brown;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 1200px; height: 600px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Create the Google Map…
    var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5195, -0.1269),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    //d3.json("stations.json", function(error, data) {

    var data = {
      "nodes": [{
        "name": "A",
        "long": 0.0000,
        "lat": 51.4800
      }, {
        "name": "B",
        "long": -0.1684,
        "lat": 51.4875
      }, {
        "name": "C",
        "long": -0.2043,
        "lat": 51.5096
      }, {
        "name": "D",
        "long": -0.1269,
        "lat": 51.5295
      }],
      "links": [{
        "source": 0,
        "target": 1
      }, {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2
      }, {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 3
      }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 3
      }]
    }

    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    overlay.onAdd = function() {
      var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
        .attr("class", "stations");

      overlay.draw = function() {
        
        layer.select('svg').remove();
        
        var projection = this.getProjection(),
          padding = 10;

        var svg = layer.append("svg")
          .attr('width', 1200)
          .attr('height', 600)

        var node = svg.selectAll(".stations")
          .data(data.nodes)
          .enter().append("g")
          .each(transform)
          .attr("class", "node");

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(data.links)
          .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .each(drawlink);

        node.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 4.5);

        node.append("text")
          .attr("x", 7)
          .attr("y", 0)
          .attr("dy", ".31em")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
          });

        function latLongToPos(d) {
          var p = new google.maps.LatLng(d.lat, d.long);
          p = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(p);
          p.x = p.x - padding;
          p.y = p.y - padding;
          return p;
        }

        function transform(d) {
          var p = latLongToPos(d);
          return d3.select(this)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")");
        }

        function drawlink(d) {
          var p1 = latLongToPos(data.nodes[d.source]),
            p2 = latLongToPos(data.nodes[d.target]);
          d3.select(this)
            .attr('x1', p1.x)
            .attr('y1', p1.y)
            .attr('x2', p2.x)
            .attr('y2', p2.y)
            .style('fill', 'none')
            .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
        }
      };
    };

    overlay.setMap(map);
    //});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Mark, this does have an issue when you zoom into the Google Map. The nodes and links are redrawn and as you repeatedly zoom you end up with multiple nodes and links drawn to the screen. Do you know how to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: @David, see edits above.  Easiest way is to remove and re-append the svg on draw:  `layer.select('svg').remove();`