# Put D3 map over google maps

Tags: google-maps, d3.js, google-maps-api-3, maps, overlay

UPDATE ***

I have added the map to the overlay but when i zoom the map is off, i dont get the zoom on the d3 map, plus how do i align my map to google? [link][1]

UPDATE 2

I have finally aligned my d3 map to google maps, but when i zoom the stays in a fixed position [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5BIh.png) and  [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1kqT.png)

This is the code : `

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.469740, 10.946157),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
styles:[{"stylers": [{"saturation": -75},{"lightness": 10}]}]
});

d3.json("weekdays0_level_2.json", function(error,data){
    if (error) throw error

    //console.log(data[0].comuni[0].geometry.coordinates);
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    overlay.onAdd = function() {

        var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")

        overlay.draw = function() {

            layer.select('svg').remove();

            var w = 900;
            var h = 600;

            var color = ['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3','#ff7f00','#ffff33','#a65628','#f781bf','#999999'];
            var heat_color = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1]).range(['#b2df8a', '#ff7f00']).interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

            var projection = d3.geo.albers()
                .center([0.13, 43.46])
                .rotate([350, 0])
                .scale(1200 * 12)
                .translate([w / 2, h / 2])
                .precision(.1);

            var path = d3.geo.path()
                         .projection(projection);

            var svg = layer.append("svg")
                .attr('width', w)
                .attr('height', h)

            for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var mapc = color[i%color.length];
                for (var j=0; j < data[i].comuni.length; j++) {
                    console.log(data[i].comuni[j])
                    svg.append("path")
                        .datum(data[i].comuni[j])
                        .attr("d", path)
                        .attr('class','state selected')
                        .style("fill", mapc)
                        .style('opacity',.7)

                }
            }
        }
    }
    overlay.setMap(map);

});
```

`

any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: It seems to me that you haven't even tried combining the google map and `d3` map.  You've just appended them one after the other.  Take a look around, there's [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711) after [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703407/on-a-google-maps-overlay-how-do-i-create-lines-between-svg-elements-in-d3) after [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps+d3.js?sort=votes&pageSize=50) of how to do this...

Comment: Can you explain how i can combine both?

Comment: I can explain it, but so do all those lovely links I just posted.  In a nut shell, create a `google.maps.OverlayView`, in that overlay, add your `d3` svg and draw in it.

Comment: i did this just like you said
https://jsfiddle.net/w2oeh1r6/ 
But i dont see anything

Comment: Ok i got the map on the layer
But i dont see it all  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_9yKhAXyyi7LWE5VXNMU08yQkk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share `weekdays0_level_3.json` with us? I will try and recreate your troubles.  In the meantime, here's more examples closer to your usecase.  The one is [overlaying topoJson](http://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/6511981) and one [overlaying geojson](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12027910/16363).

Comment: on this link you will find the file
http://demiurgo90.altervista.org/map/weekdays0_level_2.json

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I combined the [excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12027910/16363) with your data structures.  The key you are missing is the conversion of a google maps projection to one that `d3` can use.  **Note**, I also rewrote your map path code to use d3 data binding instead of loops.  Here it is in all it's runnable glory:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.469740, 10.946157),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles: [{
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": -75
        }, {
          "lightness": 10
        }]
      }]
    });

    d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/1e7c9245-e4b6-11e6-90ab-914a66f2a924", function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error

      //console.log(data[0].comuni[0].geometry.coordinates);
      var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

      overlay.onAdd = function() {

        var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")

        overlay.draw = function() {

          layer.select('svg').remove();

          var w = 900;
          var h = 600;

          var color = ['#e41a1c', '#377eb8', '#4daf4a', '#984ea3', '#ff7f00', '#ffff33', '#a65628', '#f781bf', '#999999'];
          var heat_color = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1]).range(['#b2df8a', '#ff7f00']).interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

          var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

          // Turn the overlay projection into a d3 projection
          var googleMapProjection = function(coordinates) {
            var googleCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
            var pixelCoordinates = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(googleCoordinates);
            return [pixelCoordinates.x, pixelCoordinates.y];
          }

          var path = d3.geo.path().projection(googleMapProjection);

          var svg = layer.append("svg")
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h)

          var g = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g");

          g.selectAll("path")
            .data(function(d) {
              return d.comuni;
            })
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr('class', 'state selected')
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
              return color[i % color.length];
            })
            .style('opacity', .7);

        }
      }
      overlay.setMap(map);

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes! That's it..Thanks :)